# How to use visibility "Gone" in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my windows phone app, I have a textbox which has to be displayed when certain conditions are met. If not, it should behave like **[Visibility.Gone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)** in Android.

How should I do that in a windows phone app?

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding visibility on the WinPhone platform is [Visiblity.Collapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.visibility%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: you are wrong @paiden!! __Gone__ visibility will deallocated the place reserverd for the invisible element!

Comment: Android Visbility.Gone: This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes. WinPhone Visbility.Collapsed: Do not display the element, and do not reserve space for it in layout. Is quite the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Aju If you need to reserve the space, use `Opacity=0`.

Answer (score 0):

Visiblity.Collapsed in Windows is same as Visibility.Gone in Android. In windows Elements that have a Visibility value of Collapsed do not occupy any layout space and there is nothing which is equivalent to [Visibility.InVisible](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) of Android